# Проставление прав на файлы в apache

Tags: apache, access, ubuntu

Подскажите, пожалуйста, чем мне грозит выставление прав для сайта как 777?Или как это делать правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уровень прав 777 файловой системы (а не Apache) - это доступ для всего: чтение + выполнение + запись. Т.е. полный доступ к файлам/папкам. Грозить это может всем чем угодно, начиная от изменения данных вашего сайта до изъятия его из-под вашего контроля.

Не на все папки и файлы требуется такой тип доступа. К примеру, IPBoard требует такие права только для некоторых папок. Желательно разобраться в том, какие действия необходимо будет выполнять пользователям Вашего сайта и от этого плясать. Например, для возможности загрузки фото/видео такой доступ потребуется для папки uploads.
Порекомендовал бы для дополнительной защиты сайта посмотреть в сторону SELinux.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к @Justicet. Ну, или, как минимум, НЕ менять права, установленные CMS. Если, конечно, CMS используется:)

Answer (score 0):

число, которым задают права в простейшем случае состоит из трех цифр. Первая цифра - права самого владельца файла. вторая цифра - права других участников той группы (или групп), в которой(ых) состоит владелец файла. третья цифра - права для всех других (кого угодно, включая посторонних и анонимных).

Сама цифра вычисляется тоже просто - суммированием следующих значений: 4 - право на чтение, 2 - право на запись, и 1 - право на выполнение. Итого, если "кому-то" указано 7 (а это = 4+2+1), то ему можно ВСЁ, а если 7 стоит во всех трех позициях, то это "можно всё и всем". С точки зрения безопасности - худший вариант...